# User Location returns no value

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

My code for finding user location is not giving me results, there is no error massage and no location. my code is below;

```
<!-- User Location -->
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var startPos;
        var geoSuccess = function(position) {
            startPos = position;
            document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
    };
</script>
<?php 
    echo '<script> getCurrentPosition(); </script>';
?>
```

Comment: is there any warning in console?? because it will work only on https not on http.

Comment: there is no warning, I am using localhost

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong I don't know why you have written.

```
<?php 
 echo '<script> getCurrentPosition(); </script>';
?>
```

Your have put value in "startLat" and "startLon" but where is your HTML element? you need to set html element on the page. 
**Your code should be like:**

```
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
    var startPos;
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
 };
</script>
 <div id="startLat"></div>
 <div id="startLon"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `getCurrentPosition()` any where.